# Not able to modify the Ok Cancel button in jQuery

Tags: jquery

We are using JQuery to change the orginal Ok/Cancel button to Yes/No button by calling the below function.

```
function yesnodialog(button1, button2, element)
{
    var btns = {};

    btns[button1] = function()
    { 
        element.parents('li').hide();
        $(this).dialog("close");
    };

    btns[button2] = function()
    { 
        $(this).dialog("close");
    };

    $("<div></div>").dialog(
    {
        autoOpen: true,
        title: 'Condition',
        modal:true,
        buttons:btns
    }
}
```

We added all dependent js & css files to the project but still we get an 'Object Required' error when we call the yesnodialog function

Can someone please help on this?

Comment: Where do you get the error? Did you try debugging?

Answer (score 1):

You missed `);` after the dialog call

Must be:

```
function yesnodialog(button1, button2, element)
{
    var btns = {};

    btns[button1] = function()
    { 
        element.parents('li').hide();
        $(this).dialog("close");
    };

    btns[button2] = function()
    { 
        $(this).dialog("close");
    };

    $("<div></div>").dialog(
    {
        autoOpen: true,
        title: 'Condition',
        modal:true,
        buttons:btns
    });
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JEVwA/)

Answer (score 0):

When you say `var btns = {};` you are creating an object, not an array. To add buttons to it, use the following:

```
var btns = {
  "Ok": function() {
    // Ok button pressed
  },
  "Cancel": function() {
    // Cancel button pressed
  }
};
```

Check out the documentation on jQuery UI for more information: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/